# Java Spring @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Why am I able to use this annotation - give it a value without specifying which element I'm assigning this value to? For example, I can write: `@RequestMapping("/home")` instead of `@RequestMapping(value="/home")`.

[The specs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) do not mention anything about it. Is it just a behaviour of Java annotations treating the field `value` as default one?

Comment: yes, this is default behaviour, if you only specify 1 parameter without writing "value=" it will automatically be assigned to 'value'

Comment: But the [specs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) don't say it's a default behaviour.

Comment: the requestmapping specs wouldnt specify this because this is basic annotation behaviour, and its explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html

Answer (score 0):

**Case #1:** If you have a single value then it's optional to write like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
```

In this case you may write 
`@RequestMapping("/home")` also. While providing a single string this is automatically assigned to "value". [ default behavior ]

**Case #2:** 
@RequestMapping has a String[] value parameter, so you should be able to specify multiple values like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"","/", "/away", "/home"})
```